# Chrome RDP not connecting to Ubuntu PC

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I am trying to connect my android phone to Ubuntu pc using chrome RDP on both. I setup and go online in chrome RDP in Ubuntu and tried to connect from android. I get a screen like below,
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7it4.jpg)
I tried both options. But can't connect saying the remote computer is not responding, please verify that it online and try again. I have another Ubuntu laptop and I successfully connected chrome RDP.